# mina server response port different from port incoming messages

Tags: port, mina

I set up a server that receives messages over port xxx, but I want to respond to port yyy.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

My server:

```
    IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();

    acceptor.setHandler(new MessageHandler());
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());

    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new protocolCodecFilter(codecFactory));
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(bufferSize);
    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

The encode method of my encoder:

```
public void encode(IoSession session, Object message, ProtocolEncoderOutput out) throws Exception {
    byte[] writeBytes = (byte[]) message;       
    IoBuffer buffer = IoBuffer.allocate(writeBytes.length).setAutoExpand(false);
    buffer.put(writeBytes);
    buffer.flip();
    out.write(buffer);      
    writeMessage(session,writeBytes);
}
```

The msessage should be written to a different port. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to response message using different tcp port, you must make another other tcp connection first, which means you have two servers and tow clients.

```
     request
```

client1---------->server1

```
     reponse
```

server2---------->client2